# JAXB Namespace-prefix configuration for multiple packages?

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-namespaces

First of all i would like to say i have read http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

I have multiple packages in my application , like

```
my.xml.pkg1 ,
my.xml.pkg2,
my.xml.pkg3,
my.xml.pkg4
```

etc

1. Do i need to put package-info.java in each of the packages?eg ,
   package-info.java in pkg1 , pkg2 etc ?
2. Or a global package-info.java can hold all the information. Like i
   want to put the package-info.java file in the my.xml package and
   make it work.
3. Next question arise if this one's answer is "YES" If i put a global
   package-info.java then how should i specify the XmlSchema ? What
   should be the namespace field ?
4. Is it possible to have multiple XmlRootElement in one package ?
   like I have 2 java classes containing  XMLRootElement in my.xml.pkg1 and each Root element have different namespace?In that case how do we specify the schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are my answers to your questions:

> 1 - Do i need to put package-info.java in each of the packages?eg , package-info.java in pkg1 , pkg2 etc ?

`package-info.java` is a java mechanism for applying package level metadata.  Therefore annotations put in one package do not affect another package meaning you need to do things per package.

> 2 -  Or a global package-info.java can hold all the information. Like i want to put the package-info.java file in the my.xml package and make
>   it work.

No, see answer to question 1.

> 3 -  Next question arise if this one's answer is "YES" If i put a global package-info.java then how should i specify the XmlSchema ?
>   What should be the namespace field ?

See answer to question 1.

> 4 - Is it possible to have multiple XmlRootElement in one package ? like I have 2 java classes containing XMLRootElement in my.xml.pkg1
>   and each Root element have different namespace?In that case how do we
>   specify the schema ?

Yes it is possible to have multiple `@XmlRootElement` per package.  There can only be one per class and the combination of name and namespace needs to be unique in the scope of the classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

If you have elements corresponding to different namespaces, then in terms of XML Schema you will have schemas that import other schemas since a single XML Schema corresponds to a single namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer , Can you please share with me one example of my question No. 4 ?

Comment: @Nusrat did you get example fot 4th question?

Comment: As far as I remember I have to provide unique name and namespace as Blaise said in those classes , like
 `@XmlRootElement(name = "x",namespace = "xy")`